# Meteor app stuck at loading on the client browser, clear cache needed

Tags: meteor, networking, iron-router

Every now and then, my meteor application seems to fail at loading from the browser. Switching to Incognito mode or clearing cache and cookies seems to fix the issue, but I can't understand why this happens even when I don't change anything on the server side.

[image]

I attached a network log, and the last step seems to take forever.

Things that I tried from server side are meteor rebuild command and deleting everything under .meteor/local except db folder.

Thank you